# How to enable the Portrait Effect in live camera view similar to SnapChat?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avfoundation, core-image

I have a camera view based on AVFoundation. Any idea how I can switch to Portrait Effect in iOS's Control Center like SnapChat?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to opt-in your app by [adding an Info.plist key called NSCameraPortraitEffectEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10047/?time=1306), with boolean type set to YES.

Comment: In my case I needed to restart the phone too! As weird as it sounds :D