# Swift capture photos with portrait effect matte

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I would like to implement a camera to capture portrait photos like apples default camera does. Portraiteffect and depnhdata is enabled in the PhotoSettings.

**AVCapturePhotoSettings**

```
       self.output.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
       self.output.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
         
       photoSettings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
       photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
         
       photoSettings.embedsDepthDataInPhoto = true
       photoSettings.embedsPortraitEffectsMatteInPhoto = true
```

printing the `AVCapturePhoto.portraitEffectsMatte` returns `Optional(L008 2080x1170 v.1.1)` but neither in my preview layer nor in the saved image is the portrait effect visible.

**Additional context**
AVCaptureDevice uses the builtInDualWideCamera
Printing the output.portraitEffekt logs also true

**Full code:**

````
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

 private func setUpCamera(){
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualWideCamera, for: .video, position: (useFrontCamera ? AVCaptureDevice.Position.front : AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)){
            
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if session.canAddInput(input){
                    session.addInput(input)
                }
                
                if session.canAddOutput(output){
                    session.addOutput(output)
                }
                
                previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                previewLayer.session = session
                
                session.startRunning()
                self.session = session
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

 private func getSettings() -> AVCapturePhotoSettings{
        var photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        
        if(self.output.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliverySupported && self.output.isDepthDataDeliverySupported){
            self.output.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
            self.output.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
            
            photoSettings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
            photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
            
            photoSettings.embedsDepthDataInPhoto = true
            photoSettings.embedsPortraitEffectsMatteInPhoto = true
        }
        return photoSettings
    }

   private funk takePhoto(){
 self.output.capturePhoto(with: self.getSettings(), delegate: self)
}

}

extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else { return}
    
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        
        session?.stopRunning()
        
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.frame =   CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/4, height: view.frame.height/4)
        imageView.layer.name = "photoPreview"
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, self, nil, nil)
    }
    
    
}
    ```
````

Comment: Portrait Effects Matte can be used to apply to the captured photo. It cannot be applied to the camera feed. If you mean to use Portrait Effect this might help: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706236

Comment: I still can't figure out why my photos aren't with this typical blurred background, like in the example you sent, the portraiteffectmatte is enabled for my output ;-;

Comment: Please see the answer to the question I sent. If you want the blur background effect in live camera review and captured photo, you should opt-in Portrait Effect. It's not related to the Portrait Effect Matte. To enable Portrait Effect see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276917/how-to-enable-the-portrait-effect-in-live-camera-view-similar-to-snapchat